# Laravel 5 Class cannot be found in routes.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a basic Class that cannot be found in routes.php

What've done is:

1) Generate a Model

2) Moved the Model into app/Models directory

3) Updated composer.json to include:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"     
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }

},
```

4) Run composer update

5) Added to my routes.php:

```
$myNewClass = new MyNewClass;
```

and I get `Class 'MyNewClass' not found`

Any ideas?

**MyNewClass.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyNewClass extends Model {

    //

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the App namespace on your composer file, so no need to put that in the classmap block. Just import the class on your routes.php file, i think.

```
<?php
use App\Models\MyNewClass;

$myNewClass = new MyNewClass;
```

Also, per your edit, you need to change the namespace in the top of the MyNewClass class to use App\Models instead of just App, since your model now lives in that path.